# encoding and decoding in JPG images in Android

Tags: java, android, jpeg, steganography

I am creating an application over Android where I need to manipulate my JPG files. I am not getting much of header information for JPG format so for that I am converting it to Bitmap, manipulated the pixel values in bitmap and then again convert it back to JPG.

Here what problem I am facing is- after manipulating only some pixels of bitmap and
converting it back to JPG, I do not get the same set of pixels I got earlier (for those pixels which I did not manipulate). I am getting the same image as the original in the new image. But when I check new image pixels values for decoding, the untouched pixels are different...

```
File imagefile = new File(filepath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imagefile);
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
int intArray[];
bi=bi.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);       
intArray = new int[bi.getWidth()*bi.getHeight()];
bi.getPixels(intArray, 0, bi.getWidth(), 0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());

int newArray[] = encodeImage(msgbytes,intArray,mbytes); // method where i am manipulating my pixel values 

// converting the bitmap data back to JPG file
bi = Bitmap.createBitmap(newArray, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

Bitmap bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
String filepath = "/sdcard/image/new2.jpg";
File imagefile = new File(filepath);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imagefile);
bitmapimage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

Help me if I am wrong somewhere or whether I should use some other method to manipulate JPG pixel values...

Answer (score 3):

JPEG is an image format that is usually based on [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). That means that some information that is not important for the human eye is thrown away to further shrink the file size. Try to save your image as a PNG (a lossless format).

Comment: yeah but i need to save it in JPG files as most mobile users use JPG image files....is there no way i can do all my coding in JPG n still be able to retrieve all data?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with _retrieve all the data_. By default JPEG is a lossy format and there are only a few manipulation (e.g. cropping and rotating) that can be done without lossing more information with a JPEG. At least if you open and save the image with the methods provided by the SDK you will lose information.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with using

```
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
bi = bi.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

At the point where you have the first `bi` you may have already lost a lot of information, instead try using `BitmapFactory.Options` to force `8888` (which is the default too):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inDither = false;
Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, options);
```

If you stay with `copy` you should still `recycle()` the one that you throw away.